# mat-card is not responsive in div - Angular/material

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material2

Is there any way in which I can have multiple small paper-cards displayed within a div such that they wrap around the container they are in?

Comment: Your links are not valid. Please update them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

add `flex-flow: row wrap;` (flex-flow: <‘flex-direction’> || <‘flex-wrap’>)

then `display: inline-flex;` this will make the container width equal to the content size.

```
.flex-me {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  background: grey;
}

mat-card {
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Hope this helps.